# Get all fields connected to an entity

Tags: entities

I am trying to figure out the structure of a fieldable entity.
I can see the main table in to install file, however it has various fields attached to it. How can I get an grand overview of the structure programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an entity type or bundle's field structure with [`field_info_instances()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7). e.g.

```
// Get metadata for all fields attached to the article content type.
$instances = field_info_instances('node', 'article');
```